# calling a C++ dll from C# throwing a SEHException

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I am trying to call a dll, which I build in C++, from a C# code.
However, I am getting the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in
>   dlltest_client.exe An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in
>   dlltest_client.exe External component has thrown an exception.

I am building the C++ dll using a cpp code which in turn imports a header file:

**dlltest.cpp**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "dlltest.h"

using namespace std;

// DLL internal state variables:
static string full_;
static string piece_;

void jigsaw_init(const string full_input, const string piece_input)
{
    full_ = full_input;
    piece_ = piece_input;
}

void findPiece()
{
    cout << full_;
    cout << piece_;
}
```

where **dlltest.h**:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLLTEST_EXPORTS
#define DLLTEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLTEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" DLLTEST_API void jigsaw_init(
    const std::string full_input, const std::string piece_input);

extern "C" DLLTEST_API void findPiece();
```

this successfully builds dlltest.dll

My C# code that is ought to utilise the dll is

**dlltest_client.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"path\dlltest.dll")]
    private static extern void jigsaw_init(string full_input, string piece_input);
    [DllImport(@"path\dlltest.dll")]
    private static extern void findPiece();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string full = @"path\monster_1.png";
        string piece = @"path\piece01_01.png";
        jigsaw_init(full, piece);
        findPiece();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use C++ `std::string` for unmanaged interop, which is the reason for your DLL throwing an exception.

Instead use pointer to null-terminated character array to pass strings between your C# code and the unmanaged C++ code.

The other error is that the C++ code uses cdecl calling convention, but the C# code assumes stdcall. You need to make the two sides of the interface match, change one to match the other.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting closer. However, with your suggestions implemented I only managed to pass the first character through.  C++ side: `extern "C" DLLTEST_API void jigsaw_init(char* piece_input)` and on the C# side `[DllImport(@"path\dlltest.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void jigsaw_init(string str);`

Comment: `CharSet.Unicode` passes UTF-16 encoded text. That would match `const wchar_t*` on the C++ side. Or, you could leave the C++ code as `char*` (note it really should be `const char*` and revert to `CharSet.Ansi`.